# Pure-css icon for sim cards

Tags: css

I am trying to modify the css code below to get a geometric figure like this:

[image]

...and to place some text (say, figure "1") in the middle of the icon.

```css
#diamond {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 50px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: red;
 position: relative;
 top: -50px;
}
#diamond:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: -50px;
 top: 50px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 50px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'diamond'>1</div>
```

Could you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must admit I had fun doing this, but you'd probably be better off just using a SVG image, [which you can style with CSS](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html) too - if you need that.

```css
#diamond {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  font: 48px sans-serif;
}

#diamond:before {
  content: "\00a0";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 35px 35px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'diamond'>SIM</div>
```

Comment: Patrick, thanks for answer. Could you please comment on how do you change the size of the icon ?

Comment: Just play around with the `width` and `height`, you might also need to adjust  the other px values to scale. This can become quite tedious, so my suggestion is really to use a SVG image instead.

Comment: Ok. It works now. Patrick :)) Please. One more off-topic request. How do you surround it with borders?

Comment: Not really possible, sorry. Use SVG :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you an idea what's possible with SVG and how much cleaner and maintainable this will make your CSS, here's an example. The `<path>` was generated with a vector drawing tool, then exported as SVG. You can simply put this inline with your HTML.

To change the size, adjust `width` on the `#sim` element. The rest of the CSS rules are pretty self-explanatory.

```css
#sim {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 75px;
  height: auto;
}

#sim path {
  fill: #5891A5;
  stroke: #2D678D;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

#sim text {
  fill: white;
  font: 48px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg id="sim" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="120" viewBox="0 0 180 120">
  <path d="M180,108c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12H12c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12V12C0,5.373,5.373,0,12,0h136l32,32V108z"/>
  <text x="90" y="60" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">SVG!</text>
</svg>
```